# How to get type annotation within python function scope?

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, type-hinting

For example:

```
def test():
    a: int
    b: str
    print(__annotations__)
test()
```

This function call raises a `NameError: name '__annotations__' is not defined` error.

What I want is to get the type annotation within the function `test`, like the returned dict of annotations in the global scope or class scope.

It there are any ways can achieve this ?

If it's not possiblle, why this syntax exists?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Within a function**, annotations for local variables are *not* retained, and so can't be accessed within the function. Only annotations for variables at the *module and class-level* result in an `__annotations__` object being attached.

From the [PEP 526 specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#runtime-effects-of-type-annotations):

> Annotating a local variable will cause the interpreter to treat it as a local, even if it was never assigned to. Annotations for local variables will not be evaluated[.]
>
> *[...]*
>
> In addition, at the module or class level, if the item being annotated is a simple name, then it and the annotation will be stored in the `__annotations__` attribute of that module or class[.]

The `__annotations__` global is only set if there are *actual module-level annotations defined*; the [data model states it is optional](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html):

> *Modules*
> *[...]* Predefined (writable) attributes: *[...]*; `__annotations__` (optional) is a dictionary containing variable annotations collected during module body execution; *[...]*.

When defined, you can access it from functions within the module, or via the [`globals()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals).

If you try this within a function inside a `class` statement, then know that the class body namespace is [not part of the scope of nested functions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names):

> The scope of names defined in a class block is limited to the class block; it does not extend to the code blocks of methods – this includes comprehensions and generator expressions since they are implemented using a function scope.

You'd instead access the class namespace via a reference to the class. You can get such a reference by using the class global name, or inside bound methods, via `type(self)`, inside class methods via the `cls` argument. Just use `ClassObject.__annotations__` in that case.

If you **must** have access to annotations in the function local body, you'll need to parse the source code yourself. The [Python AST](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) does retain local annotations:

```
>>> import ast
>>> mod = ast.parse("def foo():\n    a: int = 0")
>>> print(ast.dump(mod.body[0], indent=4))
FunctionDef(
    name='foo',
    args=arguments(
        posonlyargs=[],
        args=[],
        kwonlyargs=[],
        kw_defaults=[],
        defaults=[]),
    body=[
        AnnAssign(
            target=Name(id='a', ctx=Store()),
            annotation=Name(id='int', ctx=Load()),
            value=Constant(value=0),
            simple=1)],
    decorator_list=[])
```

The above shows a text representation for the body of a function with a single annotation; the `AnnAssign` node tells us that `a` is annotated as `int`. You could collect such annotations with:

```
import inspect
import ast

class AnnotationsCollector(ast.NodeVisitor):
    """Collects AnnAssign nodes for 'simple' annotation assignments"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.annotations = {}

    def visit_AnnAssign(self, node):
        if node.simple:
            # 'simple' == a single name, not an attribute or subscription.
            # we can therefore count on `node.target.id` to exist. This is
            # the same criteria used for module and class-level variable
            # annotations.
            self.annotations[node.target.id] = node.annotation

def function_local_annotations(func):
    """Return a mapping of name to string annotations for function locals

    Python does not retain PEP 526 "variable: annotation" variable annotations
    within a function body, as local variables do not have a lifetime beyond
    the local namespace. This function extracts the mapping from functions that
    have source code available.
 
    """
    source = inspect.getsource(func)
    mod = ast.parse(source)
    assert mod.body and isinstance(mod.body[0], (ast.FunctionDef, ast.AsyncFunctionDef))
    collector = AnnotationsCollector()
    collector.visit(mod.body[0])
    return {
        name: ast.get_source_segment(source, node)
        for name, node in collector.annotations.items()
    }
```

The above walker finds all `AnnAssignment` annotations in the source code for a function object (and so requires that there is a source file available), then uses the AST source line and column information to extract the annotation source.

Given your test function, the above produces:

```
>>> function_local_annotations(test)
{'a': 'int', 'b': 'str'}
```

The type hints are *not resolved*, they are just strings, so you'll still have to use the [`typing.get_type_hints()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) to turn these annotations into type objects.

Comment: Thanks for the super informative answer! Do you happen to know why annotations in a function body are not available in run time? Is it just a performance issue? 
I expected that saving an annotation (as a string) into an attribute of the variable would be cheap (and probably can be further optimized by the interpreter).

Comment: @max: variables are not objects themselves; they are merely string keys in a dictionary that forms the namespace. For functions, the local namespace isn’t even a dictionary; names are compiled to indices in an array.

Comment: @max Outside then local namespace annotations are stored as a separate dictionary on the functions (for function arguments and the return value), on classes (for class and instance attributes), and as a separate global name in the global namespace (effectively an attribute of the module). They are there for *other code* to make use of, to answer *What does this function expect to receive* sort of questions. Locals in a function are “hidden” in that they only exist while the function is running and so there is no point for anyone external to introspect their annotations.

Comment: Thanks! My use case for reading local objects' type hints in runtime was no good. I had a function `f(x: Union[List[int], List[str]])` that behaved differently based on the runtime type of `x`. Since the type of empty list cannot be deduced, I thought to require the user to pass a type-annotated variable to `f` (without any computation). Even if I could read the type annotation, it would not have worked anyway, since there is no (clean) way to find the name of the object passed into a function. Not to mention it would be an ugly solution even if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple solution I copied from others.

```py
import re
def fn(q: int):
    a: int = 1
def get_types(fn):
    source = inspect.getsource(fn)
    var_tps = re.findall("  +([a-z0-9]+) *?: *([a-z0-9]+) *=", source)
    return var_tps

get_types(fn) # [('a', 'int')]
```